# Unity Daydream distortion shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-vr, daydream

I'm working on a game for Google's daydream with the 'Pixel' phone. I'm looking for a way to play with the distortion shader, the one that renders each eyes to a `RenderTexture` in order to match the lenses distortion.

I found the following code in `StereoRenderEffect.cs`

```
using UnityEngine;

/// @cond
[RequireComponent(typeof(Camera))]
[AddComponentMenu("GoogleVR/StereoRenderEffect")]
public class StereoRenderEffect : MonoBehaviour {
#if !UNITY_HAS_GOOGLEVR || UNITY_EDITOR
  private Material material;

  private Camera cam;

  private static readonly Rect fullRect = new Rect(0, 0, 1, 1);

  void Awake() {
    cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
  }

  void Start() {
    material = new Material(Shader.Find("GoogleVR/UnlitTexture"));
  }

  void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture source, RenderTexture dest) {
    GL.PushMatrix();
    int width = dest ? dest.width : Screen.width;
    int height = dest ? dest.height : Screen.height;
    GL.LoadPixelMatrix(0, width, height, 0);
    // Camera rects are in screen coordinates (bottom left is origin), but DrawTexture takes a
    // rect in GUI coordinates (top left is origin).
    Rect blitRect = cam.pixelRect;
    blitRect.y = height - blitRect.height - blitRect.y;
    RenderTexture oldActive = RenderTexture.active;
    RenderTexture.active = dest;
    Graphics.DrawTexture(blitRect, source, fullRect, 0, 0, 0, 0, Color.white, material);
    RenderTexture.active = oldActive;
    GL.PopMatrix();
  }
#endif  // !UNITY_HAS_GOOGLEVR || UNITY_EDITOR
}
```

It allowed me to find the `UnlitTexture.shader`, which is responsible for the distortion. *However* as the `#if !UNITY_HAS_GOOGLEVR || UNITY_EDITOR`
 implies, it only works when running it in the editor. I'm looking for a way to do the same when the app runs on the actual device, but can't find it. Does someone know where to look ?

Comment: This code is to simulate the display of actual build in editor. So GVR SDK is already doing it for device build. you don't need to do this manually

Comment: I know, I just want to modify the `StereoRenderEffect` shader for my need. Adding a second full screen shader is too expensive, so I want to tweak that one.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible with Daydream and Unity.

I believe you can still do this with Cardboard and Unity, however.